# (PHP) Why is this index undefined?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I've been rattling my head over this for a few hours. I'm not sure where the issue is. I'm making a submit form and being told that an index in undefined despite using it in my code a few other times and having no issues. The issue is "quantity" at line 5, which is also giving me invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` as well.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {
            if($val==0) {
                unset($_SESSION['Cart'][$key]);
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['Cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The form uses a simple submit button to update values stored in the session (which I'm trying to make editable by plain text).

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=Cart">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $sql="SELECT * FROM products where Product_ID IN (";
            foreach($_SESSION['Cart'] as $id => $value) {
                $sql.=$id.",";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY Category ASC";
            $query=mysql_query($sql);
            $totalquantity=0;
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $subtotal=$_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity'];
                $totalquantity+=$subtotal;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
            <td><input = type="text" name="uantity [<?php echo $row['Product_ID'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity'] ?>"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }

        ?>
    </table>
    <table>
        <hr />
        <tr>
            <td><font color="Crimson"><b>Total Quantity:</b></font></td>
            <td><font color="Crimson"><b><?php echo $totalquantity ?></b></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Update selection</button>
</form>
```

There are several uses of "quantity" that work perfectly fine, such as adding up total quantity and displaying quantity in the text box, but it's showing up as undefined for line 5.

Comment: `name="uantity`?

Comment: Would also be a good idea to check that the variable is an array. `if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['quantity']) && is_array($_POST['quantity'])){`

Comment: Oh right, fixed the "uantity" thing after copying and pasting but forgot to update. Prior to that it was "Quantity" so I wanted to make it lowercase to "quantity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth just updating this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {

        if($val==0) {
            unset($_SESSION['Cart'][$key]);

        }else{
            $_SESSION['Cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
        }

    }


}
```

To:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) {

    foreach( (array) $_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val ) {

        if ( $val == 0 ) {
            unset( $_SESSION['Cart'][ $key ] );
        } else {
            $_SESSION['Cart'][ $key ]['quantity'] = $val;
        }

    }
}
```

Then fix a small typo in your code.

`<td><input = type="text" name="uantity [<?php echo $row['Product_ID'] ?>]"...`

`<td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['Product_ID'] ?>]" size="5"...`

Comment: That did it! Thanks, I see where the issue was now. Guess that's why I should take breaks instead of staring at the same code for hours trying to find a small typo and messy code.